# COBOL why does it always perform the ELSE statement also if one of the IF statement is true?

Tags: if-statement, cobol

```
IF GOAL1 = GOAL2 AND GOAL1 = 0
    PERFORM DRAW-2.
IF GOAL1 < GOAL2 OR GOAL2 > GOAL1
    PERFORM WIN-2.
IF GOAL1 > GOAL2 OR GOAL2 < GOAL1
    PERFORM WIN-1
IF GOAL1 = GOAL2
    PERFORM DRAW-1
ELSE
    DISPLAY "INVALID"
END-IF.

*FUNCTION*

WIN-1.
     DISPLAY TEAM1 " WIN".
WIN-2.
     DISPLAY TEAM2 " WIN".
DRAW-1.
     DISPLAY "BOTH TEAM DRAW".
DRAW-2.
     DISPLAY "SCORELESS DRAW".
```

Preferred output is only ONE of the if or else statements. But i got 2 outputs like TEAM1 WIN and INVALID.

Comment: What are the actual inputs & outputs?

Comment: @tenfour TEAM1 = BRAZIL, TEAM2 = URUGUAY, GOAL1 = 2, GOAL2 = 1. BRAZIL WIN and INVALID for output.

Comment: You should not be so ready to Accept.

Comment: @BillWoodger at that time after reading his answer, it triggered something in me to change my my whole code. I got what I want now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code executes the statements as you have written them. Your `ELSE` clause only applies to the final `IF` statement. Edit: Use `ELSE IF` to make the chain of `IF` statements do what you want:

```
IF GOAL1 = GOAL2 AND GOAL1 = 0
    PERFORM DRAW-2.
ELSE IF GOAL1 < GOAL2 OR GOAL2 > GOAL1
    PERFORM WIN-2.
ELSE IF GOAL1 > GOAL2 OR GOAL2 < GOAL1
    PERFORM WIN-1
ELSE IF GOAL1 = GOAL2
    PERFORM DRAW-1
ELSE
    DISPLAY "INVALID"
END-IF.
```

Comment: Thanks. Now there's just two full-stops/periods to remove from the code, and you'll need a total of four END-IFs, one for each IF. Structuring the nested-IF that way points clearly to the use of `EVALUATE`. I wonder what @Jack011, NealB and yourself think is ever going to be "invalid" :-)

Answer (score 4):

What you have here is a mixture of pre and post 1985 COBOL. Before COBOL-85 END-IF did
not exist and the only way to terminate a conditional statement (e.g. IF) was to terminate
the sentence containing it with a period (dot). The problem with using a period to terminate a conditional
statement is that it terminates not just the "closest" conditional but all conditional
statements.

Here is what your code looks like when refactored into COBOL-85:

```
IF GOAL1 = GOAL2 AND GOAL1 = 0
    PERFORM DRAW-2
END-IF

IF GOAL1 < GOAL2 OR GOAL2 > GOAL1
    PERFORM WIN-2
END-IF

IF GOAL1 > GOAL2 OR GOAL2 < GOAL1
    PERFORM WIN-1
    IF GOAL1 = GOAL2
        PERFORM DRAW-1
    ELSE
        DISPLAY "INVALID"
    END-IF
END-IF

*FUNCTION*

WIN-1.
     DISPLAY TEAM1 " WIN".
WIN-2.
     DISPLAY TEAM2 " WIN".
DRAW-1.
     DISPLAY "BOTH TEAM DRAW".
DRAW-2.
     DISPLAY "SCORELESS DRAW".
```

Now there are a few things that strike me as being odd in the above code. First
why the double conditionals such as: `IF GOAL1 < GOAL2 OR GOAL2 > GOAL1`. Clearly if
`GOAL1 < GOAL2` is true then `GOAL2 > GOAL1` must also be true! The other thing, and
this is what I believe your question is about, is that the condition that leads to
performing paragraph `WIN-1` is only true when `GOAL1 NOT = GOAL2` so the second imbedded
conditional `IF GOAL1 = GOAL2` cannot be true leading to the `ELSE` resulting in `DISPLAY "invalid"`

With COBOL-85 there are more structured ways of doing what I think you wanted to do
here. Try the following:

```
 EVALUATE TRUE
     WHEN GOAL1 = ZERO AND
          GOAL2 = ZERO
          PERFORM DRAW-2
     WHEN GOAL1 = GOAL2
          PERFORM DRAW-1
     WHEN GOAL1 > GOAL2
          PERFORM WIN-1
     WHEN GOAL1 < GOAL2
          PERFORM WIN-2
     WHEN OTHER
          DISPLAY "invalid"
 END-EVALUATE
```

I think this is a little easier to understand and does not use periods to terminate the
scope of conditional statements.

Comment: Typical :-) I didn't see this when suggesting not worth EVALUATE, by the way. Much clearer than the original.

Comment: @NealB I don't even know that this method existed, I should learn more. Wouldn't the WHEN condition 1 and 2 perform if I put 0 as both goal1 and goal2 input?

Comment: @Jack011 Once a `WHEN` is actioned, that is the end of the `EVALUATE`. Don't expect things to necessarily work like something from another language with a superficially similar structure.

Answer (score 1):

That is very convoluted code for a simple thing.

Your problem is missing a full-stop/period on the third IF. You shouldn't use full-stops/periods to terminate IFs, you should always use END-IF (wihtout a full-stop/period unless dictated by your local standards for some silly reason). Have a look at this recent question: [Dot rules in nested conditional statements - COBOL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24504942/1927206)

The Answer you have Accepted is incorrect. If you nest those IFs, and have a final ELSE, that ELSE will simply apply to the last IF of the nest, and have nothing to do with the rest.

Superficially, EVALUATE would better-suit what you want. However:

```
    IF GOAL1 EQUAL TO GOAL2 
        PERFORM A-DRAW
    ELSE
        PERFORM A-WIN
    END-IF
    .
A-DRAW.
    IF TEAM1-NO-GOALS
        DISPLAY "SCORELESS DRAW"
    ELSE
        DISPLAY "SCORE DRAW"
    END-IF
    .    
A-WIN.
    IF GOAL1 GREATER THAN GOAL2
        DISPLAY TEAM1 " WIN"
    ELSE
        DISPLAY TEAM2 " WIN"
    END-IF
    .
```

TEAM1-NO-GOALS is an 88-level condition-name on GOAL1.

Obviously the DISPLAY lines could be replaced by PERFORM of your original paragraphs, although you should make the names more meaningful - what's wrong with paragraphs like TEAM1-WINS or SCORE-DRAW at least?

Comment: The reason I mark him correct because at that time he was the only one fast enough to answer my question and after reading what he wrote, something triggered in me to change my whole code to get what I want. Anyway, my mistake for deciding too fast and careless.

Comment: @Jack011 No problem. Hopefully they will return and correct the answer so as not to confuse future readers.